# How can I turn the values inside a UL into an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, regex, arrays, strip-tags

I have a ul list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>                        
       <div class="time">18:45</div>
       <div class="info">description goes here</div>
       <div class="clearAll"></div>
    </li>

    <li>                        
       <div class="time">19:15</div>
       <div class="info">some info</div>
   <div class="clearAll"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I turn this into an array like this:

```
$array = array(
    1 => array('18:45','description goes here');
    1 => array('19:15','some info');
);
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: DomDocument will do it...with a little bit of engineering. ;)

Comment: What you need is a very big `str_replace()` =p

Comment: What have you tried so far? Am I free to presume that you don't want an array with two members called `1`?

Comment: Search for `php parse xml` here on Stack Overflow

Comment: I've tried
    $return = strip_tags($programme);
    $return = explode("\n",$return);
and then looping through it. but it's not very clever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stay away from a regex for this. [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is your friend:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $theHTMLstring );
$array = array();

foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li ) {

    $divs = $li->getElementsByTagName('div');

    $array[] = array(
        $divs->item(0)->textContent,
        $divs->item(1)->textContent
    );
}
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/5ExOqJ

Answer (score 0):

By not using regex:

```
$sx = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($sx->xpath('//li') as $node) {
   $time = current($node->xpath("div[@class='time']"));
   $time = "$time";

   $info = current($node->xpath("div[@class='info']"));
   $info = "$info";

   $data[] = array($time, $info);
}
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/lo8k5c